# WebDriver not opening URL

Tags: selenium, webdriver, testng

I'm very new to selenium so I'm having trouble spotting the problem with my code. I'm using a webDriver backed selenium object, it starts the driver but never opens the URL and the driver just closes after a few moments. The last time this happened to me it was just because I had left "http" out of the URL. So what's causing it this time?

```
public void testImages() throws Exception {
Selenium selenium = new WebDriverBackedSelenium(driver, "http://www.testsite.com/login"); 
System.out.println(selenium.getXpathCount("//img"));
}
```

The setup looks like:

```
public void setUp() throws Exception {
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\User1\\Desktop\\chromedriver_win_16.0.902.0\\chromedriver.exe");
driver = new ChromeDriver();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
}
```

The teardown method just consists of driver.close().
I'm using selenium 2.14 and the testNG Eclipse plug-in.

Comment: Also I've tried the firefox and IE drivers and same thing happens. I would be grateful for any help at all! :)

Answer (score 1):

You might need to do the following

`selenium.open("www.testsite.com/login");`

Check out this example from the selenium site:

```
// You may use any WebDriver implementation. Firefox is used here as an example
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

// A "base url", used by selenium to resolve relative URLs
 String baseUrl = "http://www.google.com";

// Create the Selenium implementation
Selenium selenium = new WebDriverBackedSelenium(driver, baseUrl);

// Perform actions with selenium
selenium.open("http://www.google.com");
selenium.type("name=q", "cheese");
selenium.click("name=btnG");

// Get the underlying WebDriver implementation back. This will refer to the
// same WebDriver instance as the "driver" variable above.
WebDriver driverInstance = ((WebDriverBackedSelenium) selenium).getUnderlyingWebDriver();

//Finally, close the browser. Call stop on the WebDriverBackedSelenium instance
//instead of calling driver.quit(). Otherwise, the JVM will continue running after
//the browser has been closed.
selenium.stop();
```

[link to selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html#webdriver-backed-selenium-rc)

Answer (score 0):

You would need to add driver.get(url) like below.

```
public void setUp() throws Exception {
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\User1\\Desktop\\chromedriver_win_16.0.902.0\\chromedriver.exe");
driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("http://www.testsite.com/login");
}
```